How avoid user resending Ajax POST request to Flask app, overwriting data?
A Python Flask app renders a HTML page, using the Geolocation API to record coordinates. Javascript then POSTS this data to the /submit_location endpoint of said Flask app to record it in a database that is not publicly accessible.
How can we avoid the user editing and resending this request to record false data in the database (apart from not allowing data to be overwritten)?
Sending a secret token in the JSON data, to be compared by the endpoint to a local environment variable, can be seen by the user and so can a CSRF token in the headers which can be reused during the session. Restricting the IP of the requestor to localhost only can be spoofed.

You can't. Servers should never trust information from the client, there's nothing stopping the user from modifying it with DevTools.

Use IP Geolocation on the server rather than depending on the location reported by the client.

I think you'll have to perform validation on both the server and client side since client-side measures alone won't fully prevent users from tampering with the coordinates. A hash-based message authentication code (HMAC) algorithm could help the server identify if the coordinates were modified.
This usually entails generating an HMAC signature on the server using a secret key, which the client cannot access, and then combining this with the coordinates and a unique identifier (like a nonce or timestamp). If a user intercepts the request and changes the coordinates, they won't have the secret key needed to generate the HMAC so the server can tell from the invalid HMAC that the coordinates have been altered.
Here's an article on implementing HMAC request signing: https://blog.andrewhoang.me/how-api-request-signing-works-and-how-to-implement-it-in-nodejs-2/
